# Why is unserialize_callback_func needed when spl_autoload_register is already used?

Tags: php, spl-autoload-call

```
ini_set('unserialize_callback_func', 'spl_autoload_call');

spl_autoload_register(array(self::getInstance(), 'autoload'));
```

Why set [`spl_autoload_call`](http://cn.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-call.php) like above?

I made a test:

```
$serialized_object='O:1:"a":1:{s:5:"value";s:3:"100";}';

ini_set('unserialize_callback_func','mycallback');

function mycallback($classname) {
    echo 1;
}

function func2() 
{
    echo 2;
}

spl_autoload_register('func2');
unserialize($serialized_object);
```

The output is:

```
212
```

Can someone explain this?

Comment: Did you by any chance come up with this question from looking at the symfony code?

Comment: Yes!I'm reviewing the symfony code to know how it works exactly!It's derived from the `register` method in sfCoreAutoload.class.php

Answer (score 18):

I did some tests, and here are the notes I took *(hope it'll be understandable ^^ ;; and that I didn't get too lost in my own thought ^^ )*

*Note : I've done my tests on PHP 5.3.2-dev, in case it matters.*

First of all, let's define a `temp-2.php` file, that's going to contain only this :

```
<?php

class a {
    
}
```

i.e. the definition of the class that corresponds to the object we'll be trying to unserialize.

And all other portions of code I will post will be contained in a file called `temp.php` -- which would have to include `temp-2.php` so the class' definition is known.

First try : we try to unserialize the string, without having defined the class `a` :

```
$serialized_object='O:1:"a":1:{s:5:"value";s:3:"100";}';

function callback_spl($className)  {
    var_dump(__FUNCTION__ . ' : ' . $className);
}

spl_autoload_register('callback_spl');
$data = unserialize($serialized_object);
var_dump($data);
```

As output, we get this :

```
string 'callback_spl : a' (length=16)

object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)[1]
  public '__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name' => string 'a' (length=1)
    public 'value' => string '100' (length=3)
```

Which means that :

- The autoloading function `callback_spl` has been called

  - even if registered by `spl_autoload_register`
  - But it has not autoloaded anything
- And, as the class as not been autoloaded, we get an object that's an instance of `__PHP_Incomplete_Class`

Now, let's try using `spl_autoload_register` to register an autoloading function that actually autoloads the class' definition :

```
$serialized_object='O:1:"a":1:{s:5:"value";s:3:"100";}';

function callback_spl($className)  {
    var_dump(__FUNCTION__ . ' : ' . $className);
    require dirname(__FILE__) . '/temp-2.php';
}

spl_autoload_register('callback_spl');
$data = unserialize($serialized_object);
var_dump($data);
```

And we get this ouput :

```
string 'callback_spl : a' (length=16)

object(a)[1]
  public 'value' => string '100' (length=3)
```

Which means :

- The autoloading function registered by `spl_autoload_register` has been called

  - And, this time, it did require the file containing the definition of the class
- The un-serialization has been successful

  - i.e. we don't get an instance of `__PHP_Incomplete_Class` anymore,
  - we actually get an instance of `a`

**So, here, I would say that `unserialize_callback_func` is not needed when `spl_autoload_register` is used.**

*I think, here, that I've kind of answered the question ? But I'll post a couple of other tests, just for fun ^^*

---

Now, what if we try using `unserialize_callback_func`, and not using `spl_autoload_register` ?

The code will look like his, I suppose :

```
$serialized_object='O:1:"a":1:{s:5:"value";s:3:"100";}';

ini_set('unserialize_callback_func', 'callback_no_spl');

function callback_no_spl($className)  {
    var_dump(__FUNCTION__ . ' : ' . $className);
    require dirname(__FILE__) . '/temp-2.php';
}

$data = unserialize($serialized_object);
var_dump($data);
```

And, as output, we get :

```
string 'callback_no_spl : a' (length=19)

object(a)[1]
  public 'value' => string '100' (length=3)
```

So, everything works OK :

- The `callback_no_spl` callback function registered via `unserialize_callback_func` is called

  - It loads the definition of the class
- And the data is unserialized properly

  - i.e. we get an instance of `a`

Going a bit farther, let's try what we can get when both :

- Setting an autoload function, called `callback_no_spl`, with `unserialize_callback_func`
- And setting another autoload function, called `callback_spl`, with `spl_autoload_register`

The code will look like this :

```
$serialized_object='O:1:"a":1:{s:5:"value";s:3:"100";}';

ini_set('unserialize_callback_func', 'callback_no_spl');
function callback_no_spl($className)  {
    var_dump(__FUNCTION__ . ' : ' . $className);
    require dirname(__FILE__) . '/temp-2.php';
}

spl_autoload_register('callback_spl');
function callback_spl($className)  {
    var_dump(__FUNCTION__ . ' : ' . $className);
    require dirname(__FILE__) . '/temp-2.php';
}

$data = unserialize($serialized_object);
var_dump($data);
```

And the output we get :

```
string 'callback_spl : a' (length=16)

object(a)[1]
  public 'value' => string '100' (length=3)
```

Which means :

- only the autoloading function registered with `spl_autoload_register` has been called
- It did load the file that contains the class' definition
- And the data has been unserialized properly.

Now, just for fun, what if we try changing the order in which we set the autoloaders ?

i.e. use this portion of code :

```
$serialized_object='O:1:"a":1:{s:5:"value";s:3:"100";}';

spl_autoload_register('callback_spl');
function callback_spl($className)  {
    var_dump(__FUNCTION__ . ' : ' . $className);
    require dirname(__FILE__) . '/temp-2.php';
}

ini_set('unserialize_callback_func', 'callback_no_spl');
function callback_no_spl($className)  {
    var_dump(__FUNCTION__ . ' : ' . $className);
    require dirname(__FILE__) . '/temp-2.php';
}

$data = unserialize($serialized_object);
var_dump($data);
```

We get exactly the same output as before :

```
string 'callback_spl : a' (length=16)

object(a)[1]
  public 'value' => string '100' (length=3)
```

Which seems to indicate that the autoloader defined with `spl_autoload_register` as a higher priority than the one defined with `unserialize_callback_func`.

What else can I test ?

Oh, let's test setting both autoloading functions, but have the one registered by `spl_autoload_register` *(i.e. the one with the highest priority)* not actually load the class' definition :

```
$serialized_object='O:1:"a":1:{s:5:"value";s:3:"100";}';

ini_set('unserialize_callback_func', 'callback_no_spl');
function callback_no_spl($className)  {
    var_dump(__FUNCTION__ . ' : ' . $className);
    require dirname(__FILE__) . '/temp-2.php';
}

spl_autoload_register('callback_spl');
function callback_spl($className)  {
    var_dump(__FUNCTION__ . ' : ' . $className);
    //require dirname(__FILE__) . '/temp-2.php';        // We don't load the class' definition
}

$data = unserialize($serialized_object);
var_dump($data);
```

This time, here's the ouput we get :

```
string 'callback_spl : a' (length=16)

string 'callback_no_spl : a' (length=19)

object(a)[1]
  public 'value' => string '100' (length=3)
```

Basically :

- The autoloading function registered with `spl_autoload_register` has been called

  - It did not load the class' definition
- So the autoloading function registered with `unserialize_callback_func` has been called

  - And it did load the class' definition
  - So, we've obtained the data properly un-serialized.

Now, let's come back to the code example you posted -- translated to *my* functions names, it would give us something like this, I suppose :

```
$serialized_object='O:1:"a":1:{s:5:"value";s:3:"100";}';

ini_set('unserialize_callback_func', 'callback_no_spl');
function callback_no_spl($className)  {
    var_dump(__FUNCTION__ . ' : ' . $className);
    //require dirname(__FILE__) . '/temp-2.php';        // We don't load the class' definition
}

spl_autoload_register('callback_spl');
function callback_spl($className)  {
    var_dump(__FUNCTION__ . ' : ' . $className);
    //require dirname(__FILE__) . '/temp-2.php';        // We don't load the class' definition
}

$data = unserialize($serialized_object);
var_dump($data);
```

And, this time, I get the same kind of thing as you did :

```
string 'callback_spl : a' (length=16)
string 'callback_no_spl : a' (length=19)
string 'callback_spl : a' (length=16)

( ! ) Warning: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Function callback_no_spl() hasn't defined the class it was called for ...

object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)[1]
  public '__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name' => string 'a' (length=1)
  public 'value' => string '100' (length=3)
```

And, this time :

- The function registered with `spl_autoload_register` is called

  - And doesn't load the class' definition
- Then, the function registered with `unserialize_callback_func` is called

  - It doesn't load the class' defition either...
- Like magic, the function registered with `spl_autoload_register` is called again !

  - It still doesn't load the class' definition
- And boom, we get a warning saying that the function registered with `unserialize_callback_func` did not load the class' definition

  - Note this only happens after `callback_spl` has been called for the second time !
  - Which seems to indicate that there is some kind of autoloading happening even if the function defined with `unserialize_callback_func` didn't load what it should have...

I have to admit, this is both nice and tricky -- and I have quite no idea why this is happening, as it doesn't seem to make much sense...

I suppose this *strange* behavior has to do with the fact that :

- [`unserialize_callback_func`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/var.configuration.php#unserialize-callback-func) exists since PHP 4.2
- while [`spl_autoload_register`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) only exists since PHP 5.1
  and [`__autoload`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) has been introduced in PHP 5

The "stack / queue" behavior of `spl_autoload_register`, I suppose, can have some interferences with the old behavior of `unserialize_callback_func`...

Comment: Uh... a TL;DR is definitely needed!

Comment: Very helpful answer. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

unserialize() requires class definition loaded before actually unserializing data. unserialize_callback_func is called when class definition is not loaded and spl_autoload_call tries to use all autoloaders registered to load class needed for unserialize().

Comment: Aren't functions registered in `spl_autoload_register` loaded automatically?

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but the question isn't what `unserialize_callback_func` does but why you have to register a perfectly working autoloader again as unserialize_callback.

Comment: I've answered it when question was "When will spl_autoload_call get called?". That's why answer is odd.

Comment: Should not be a reason to use such code in Symfony, but unserialize_callback_func was in PHP 4 while spl_autoload_register was added in PHP 5.1.2.