# How do I get around ini_set disabled when trying to autoload

Tags: php, spl-autoload-register, ini-set

I'm writing a WordPress plugin that uses Raven, which uses autoload in the following way:

```
ini_set('unserialize_callback_func', 'spl_autoload_call');
spl_autoload_register(array(new self, 'autoload'));
```

However, some users of the plugin have ini_set disabled by their host providers, and an error gets thrown when the plugin is activated:

Warning: ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons in...

Is there a way I can get around using ini_set in this case?

I guess my real question is if ini_set necessary when using spl_autoload_register or not?

Comment: If something's disabled *for security reasons*, adding an `@` sign in front of it is extremely unlikely to by-pass that security! Either your code works without the `ini_set` line succeeding, or it doesn't, and that should be pretty easy to test by removing the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2405422/53212) states that you probably don't need to set `unserialize_callback_func` anymore when using `spl_autoload_register()`.

Comment: looked at that answer previously and wasn't sure if it matched my exact needs, i'll give it a shot and report my findings

Comment: I commented out the ini_set line and it appears to work okay, will report any issues that arise